# error in derived class 'no type named my_data in <base class>'

Tags: c++, inheritance, boost, constructor, composition

In my code I use a templated multi-dimensional container class `array_dyn<T>`, which has a property `my_data` that is a `std::vector<T>`.

To keep things separable I use my own class `bisArray<T>` that inherits from `array_dyn`:

```
typedef array_dyn<T>                   super_type;
typedef typename super_type::index_t   index_t;

template < typename Sizes >
bisArray( dirs a_dir, Sizes const& a_sizes={} ): 
        super_type ( a_dir, a_sizes ),   super_type::my_data( super_type::size()) {}
template < typename Sizes >
bisArray( Sizes const& a_sizes={} ): 
        super_type ( dir_fwd, a_sizes ), super_type::my_data( super_type::size()) {}
```

Here, `dir_fwd` (and `dir_rev`) represents c (and fortran) storage order.
The array_dyn class is here [ https://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/variadic_templates/sandbox/array_dyn ].

Happy to provide more code, but I think the problem that I get is caused here: when I use

```
std::vector<size_t> newsizes({2,3});
bisArray<int>       newarray(newsizes); // using constructor #2
```

Then there is an error message

```
no type named my_data in struct 'array_dyn<int>'
```

Previous StackOverflow posts about this error mentioned circular definitions and forward declarations; but that is not what I am doing here. I just inherit from `array_dyn`, which has a property `my_data`, but when I create an object with the derived class bisArray, it says that its base class does not have this property.

Am I using the wrong inheritance mechanism? Or the wrong access method?

Comment: I think the problem is that you may only initialize members of your own class in the mem-initializer-list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:
You can't initialize base class members in the constructor of a derived class.

You may want to try something like this instead (assuming that my_data has a suitable setter method):

```
template < typename Sizes >
bisArray( dirs a_dir, Sizes const& a_sizes={} ): 
    super_type ( a_dir, a_sizes ) {
    super_type::my_data.set_size( super_type::size());
}
```

Longer version, the best explanation I could find from the [C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3376.pdf) is in paragraph 12.6.1.10:

> In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the following order:
>
> — First, and only for the constructor of the most derived class (1.8), virtual base classes are initialized in the order they appear on a depth-ﬁrst left-to-right traversal of the directed acyclic graph of base classes, where “left-to-right” is the order of appearance of the base classes in the derived class base-speciﬁer-list.
>
> — Then, direct base classes are initialized in declaration order as they appear in the base-speciﬁer-list (regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).
>
> — Then, non-static data members are initialized in the order they were declared in the class deﬁnition (again regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).
>
> — Finally, the compound-statement of the constructor body is executed

Now, this may sound a bit round-about, but the constraint that non-static data members are initialized in the order in which they were declared in the class definition implies that you can't initialize base-class members in a derived class.

Comment: ah, thanks for the short answer! well, since super_type::my_data is a std::vector, I guess that would just be my_data.resize()?

Comment: The only way in which I can get it to work is by using `super_type::my_data.resize( super_type::size()) ;` -- any idea why `super_type::` is needed? The new class inherits `my_data` so that should not be necessary?

Comment: @alle_meije a member of a dependent base class (`my_data`'s base class `array_dyn<T>` depends on the template `T` in this case) has to be disambiguated by typing `this->`, `array_dyn<T>::` or its alias `super_type::`. Note that Visual C++ will let you get away with it, but on g++/clang the Standard is enforced on this point.

Answer (score 1):

### You probably shouldn't be (ab)using inheritance...

**Question**: why do you use inheritance for `bisArray<T>`?

Is it to add extra functionality to `array_dyn<T>` that can entirely be written in the public interface of `array_dyn<T>`? In that case, add non-member functions to provide that functionality instead of inheriting and adding member functions. So instead of

```
template<class T>
class bisArray: public array_dyn<T>
{
public:
     void doCoolStuffThatBoostDoesNotProvide() const;
};
```

write a **non-member function**

```
template<class T>
void doCoolStuffThatBoostDoesNotProvide(array_dyn<T> const& s);
```

If you need to add functionality that requires extra state to a `array_dyn<T>`, use **composition**

```
template<class T>
class bisArray
{
public: 
     void doCoolStuffThatBoostCannotImplement() const;
private:
     some_fancy_type s_;
     array_dyn<T> a_;
};
```

`array_dyn<T>` was never designed to be a base class. For one, it doesn't have a **virtual destructor**. Second, the designers of `array_dyn<T>` also composed a `std::vector<T>`, and did not inherit from it, for exactly those reasons.

Of course, when using composition, `bisArray<T>` will have to redefine the entire interface (members and constructors) that it wants to keep. However, in the words of [**Alexandrescu and Sutter**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321113586):

> Admittedly, it's tedious to have to write passthrough functions for
>   the member functions you want to keep, but such an implementation is
>   vastly better and safer than using public or nonpublic inheritance.

### ... but use the base constructors if you do...

OK, you absolutely-positively-definitely want to use inheritance. Well that's easy: just delegate all work to the `array_dyn<T>` base class constructor:

```
template
  < typename Sizes
  >
array_dyn( dirs a_dir, Sizes const& a_sizes={})
: super_t( a_dir, a_sizes)
, my_data( super_t::size())
{
}
```

Your two requested constructors can then be gotten from your current version minus the initialization of `my_data` because the `array_dyn<T>` constructor already does the exact same amount of work

```
// note use explicit keyword for single-argument constructors
template<typename Sizes>
explicit bisArray( dirs a_dir, Sizes const& a_sizes={} )
: super_type(a_dir, a_sizes) 
{}

template < typename Sizes >
bisArray( Sizes const& a_sizes={} )
: super_type(dir_fwd, a_sizes)
{}
```

In case you want to set `super_type::my_data` to another value than what the `super_type` constructor does, just put such a statement in the body of the constructor. But from the Boost code and your code alone that doesn't seem to be required here.

### ... or use factory functions to get the best of both worlds

Still, if all that `bisArray<T>` does is create a default constructor that takes the C-array style parameter `dir_fwd`, why not drop the inheritance, and write two non-member factory functions that return a `array_dyn<T>` with the corresponding constructor arguments

```
template<typename T, typename Sizes>
make_fortran_array_dyn(Sizes const& a_sizes={} )
{
    return array_dyn<T>(dir_rev, a_sizes);
}

template <typename T, typename Sizes >
make_c_array_dyn( Sizes const& a_sizes={} )
{
     return array_dyn<T>(dir_fwd, a_sizes);
}
```

which you can call like this:

```
auto c = make_c_array_dyn<double>(your_sizes);
auto f = make_fortran_array_dyn<double>(your_sizes);
```

Comment: Thanks @TemplateRex for this extensive overview! To visit your points: [1] the idea is to add more functionality to bisArray (as said it's partly implemented) which will probably require a new class (so inheritance without initialising base class members in the constructor is the way to go) [2] array_dyn does not inherit from vector, but it does inherit from box_domain (which provides the indexing without the storage). [3] why is composition better/safe than inheritance? has it got to do with performance? [4] the factory example looks like it does the same as composition?

Comment: @alle_meije [1] initializing base members is best done through the base constructor, as shown above. If the new functionality can be implemented with the public interface of `array_dyn<T>`, it's best to write non-member function. [This increases encapsulation](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197). [4] the factory approach does not need a new class template `bisArray<T>`, but simply defines a non-member function template `make_C_array_dyn<T>` in terms of its constructors.

Comment: @alle_meije [2]/[3]: [overuse of inheritance](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill06.htm) is a serious design error, but hard to explain inside this margin. [Alexandrescu & Sutter](http://www.amazon.com/Coding-Standards-Rules-Guidelines-Practices/dp/0321113586) have several Items devoted to it.

Comment: @alle_meije Two things from A&S: a) "Inheriting from a type can cause name lookup to pull in functions and function templates defined in the same namespace as that type. This is very subtle and hard to debug." b) "inheriting from a class without a virtual destructor risks littering your code with undefined behavior by delete-ing pointers to Base classes that actually point to Derived objects. This undefined behavior might seem to be tolerated by your compiler and memory allocator, but it leaves you in the dark swamp of silent errors, memory leaks, heap corruptions, and porting nightmares."